# Missing the assembly option for references in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am following a tutorial to learn c# visual studio app development. The video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfWxdh-_k_4&t=21714s. At 6:01:21 in the video, he opens his references tab and there are 5 categories, projects, assemblies, shared projects, COM and browse. I am missing the assemblies tab and cannot find the references he is looking for in any of the other tabs. Note: he opens his reference tab in references and mine in assemblies but I assume this to be caused by differences in version.

Comment: What kind of project are you working on, .NET Framework or .NET Core (aka .NET)

Answer (score 1):

Because your project file (.csproj) was created in Project SDK format. In the video, it's non-SDK format. Usually, when you created an project with.NET Framework project template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format

Comment: I read through these documents and they help me understand the problem but do you know of a solution (there is a good chance I missed a solution in them the programming jargon is difficult for me to understand) that would be helpful.

Comment: If you want to do like the video, then at creating project step, you select the type of project is Class Library for .NET Framework.